# Visual Studio Nuget dll not found in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a multi-project solution.  In fact, some projects happen to be shared by 2 different solutions.

Anyhow, one of these is a test project and uses RhinoMocks.  I used NUGET to add this to the project, and the solution is set to enable the download any packages from NUGET.

It builds just fine when in DEBUG mode, but when I put it into RELEASE mode, I get:

> *Error    1   The type or namespace name 'Rhino' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I don't think it's limited to RhinoMock, I've occassionally got it with NUNIT too.

Any ideas here?

Thanks

Comment: Open your references, find Rhino, right click, properties, then check where the reference is pointing to.  Do the same in debug mode. Why are they different? Unload the project file, edit it, seek out the incorrect path, switch it for the correct one, The Aristocrats.

Comment: Will - the problem was that it was a project shared by 2 solutions, so the hint path was correct for one, but wrong for the other.  I fixed this by changing the hint paths so that it's correct for both solutions.

Comment: You should add that as an answer below in order to close out this question.